# IDA Pro only shows dos stub of windows executables/libraries

Tags: ida, pe

When I load most windows NE/PE executables, IDA first warns me about the file being possibly packed, then it warns me with this dialog: "*The input file has extra information at the end (tail < hex >, loaded < hex >), continue?*". It loads the file, but only shows the "*This program cannot be run in DOS mode.*" DOS stub and that's it. No import/export tables, structs, etc.

How can I force IDA to recognize the PE header and load that instead of the DOS stub?

Answer (score 3):

Normally it should be selected by default but...

[image]

Comment: It doesn't show up as an option. Only binary file or MS-DOS executable show up.

Comment: pe.ldw also is missing from the IDA loaders directory. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: @Discord If you are on windows try *[IDA 5.0](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/download_freeware.shtml)* in case your copy of IDA is corrupted.

Comment: I managed to recover a copy of pe.ldw. Thanks for the help.